# Google Firestore - Efficiently fetch a single document, perform a point query within a subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Assume I am designing a new Firestore database. Assume I like the idea of a hierarchical design and, as a contrived example, each **Year** has a sequence of child **Weeks** of which each has **Days**.

What's the most *performance efficient* way to retrieve a single document for today? i.e. 2021-W51-Thursday

Answers are permitted to include changes to the model, e.g. "denormalizing" the day model such that it includes `year`, `week` and `dayName` fields (and querying them).

Otherwise a simple document reference may be the fastest way, like:

```
DocumentReference ref = db
    .Collection("years").Document("2021")
    .Collection("weeks").Document("51")
    .Collection("days").Document("Thursday");
```

Thanks.

Comment: While this could be answered in a platform-agnostic way, it helps to also include which SDKs you are likely to be using and the types of queries you are going to make.

Comment: Probably the trickiest thing regarding querying over hierarchies is that "searching for all Thursdays in 2021" can quickly become a pain involving multiple queries. I'd also consider using `2021-W51-4` instead of `2021-W51-Thursday` - if shown in an interface, they would be sorted chronologically (instead of Friday above Thursday).

Comment: Reading a single document by specifying its full path is the fastest way to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any query that identifies a single document to fetch is equally performant to any other query that does the same *at the scale that Firestore operates*.  The organization of collections or documents does not matter at al *at scale*.  You might see some fluctuations in performance at small scale, depending on your data set, but that's not how Firestore is optimized to work.

All collections and all subcollections each have at least one index on the ID of the document that works the same way, independent of each other collection and index.  If you can identify a unique document using its path:

```
/db/XXXX/weeks/YY/days/ZZZZ
```

Then it scales the same as a document stored using a more flat structure:

```
/db/XXXXYYZZZZ
```

It makes no difference *at scale*, since indexes on collections scale to an infinite number of documents with no theoretical upside limit.  That's the magic of Firestore: if the system allows the query, then it will always perform well.  You don't worry about scaling and performance at all.  The indexes are automatically sharded across computing resources to optimize performance (vs. cost).

All of the above is true for fields of a document (instead of a document ID).  You can think of a document ID as a field of a document that must be unique within a collection.  Each field has its own index by default, and it scales massively.

With NoSQL databases like Firestore, you should structure your data in such a way that eases your queries, as long as those queries can be supported by indexes that operate *at scale*.  This stands in contrast with SQL databases, which are optimized for query flexibility rather than massive scalability.